# two repeating numbers in the final result of intersection of two arrays

Tags: java

So, my task is to intersect two arrays, but its not allowed to have 2 repeating elements in the final result. I got to this code, but it doesnt satisfy the task, because if it has 2 same numbers in each array, in the final result they both appears. Any suggestions?

```
static void printIntersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int m = arr1.length;
    int n = arr2.length;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while ((i < m) && (j < n)) {
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
            System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }
}

static void printArray(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] arr2 = {2, 2, 3, 5, 7};

    System.out.println("Array1:");
    printArray(arr1);

    System.out.println("Array2:");
    printArray(arr2);

    System.out.println("Union:");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Intersection:");
    printIntersection(arr1, arr2);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a `list/array` to check whether there's a duplicate element.
Using `ArrayList` is an option:

```
static void printIntersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int m = arr1.length;
        int n = arr2.length;
        int i=0,j=0;

        while((i<m) && (j<n)) {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                if(!list.contains(arr1[i]))
                {
                    System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
                    list.add(arr1[i]);
                }
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else if(arr1[i] < arr2[j])
                i++;
            else
                j++;
        }
    }
```

N.B.: I haven't tested your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part.
If an element in `arr1` matches an element in `arr2`,
it will print it and increment the two counters.

> ```
> if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
>     System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
>     i++;
>     j++;
> }
> ```

The condition above says nothing about duplicate elements in `arr1` itself.
You need to add more conditions to handle that.

It seems your input arrays are sorted.
In that case, you could add conditions to only print the value and increment `j` when the element of `arr1` is different from the previous, for example:

```
if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
    if (i == 0 || arr1[i - 1] != arr1[i]) {
        System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```